# Apollo server 4 getting a POST /graphql 404 after setting up using expressMiddleware

Tags: apollo-server

**Here is my set up**

```
//From my services set up

const { ApolloServer } = require ("@apollo/server");
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require ("@graphql-tools/schema");
const {ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer } = require ('@apollo/server/plugin/drainHttpServer');
const express = require('express')
const { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault } = require( "@apollo/server/plugin/landingPage/default");
const http = require('http')

const  resolvers = require ('./resolvers.js');
const  typeDefinitions = require ("./schema.js");
const app = express()

const executableSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: typeDefinitions,
  resolvers: resolvers,
});

const httpServer = http.createServer(app);


const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema: executableSchema,
  plugins: [
    ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),
    ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault({ includeCookies: true })
  ]
});

if (exports) {
  exports.server = server
}
```

````
// I retrieve the service from the services module one includes graphql

const serviceNames = Object.keys(services);
for (let i = 0; i < serviceNames.length; i++) {
  const name = serviceNames[i];
  if (name === "graphql") {
    (async () => {
      let server = services[name].server;
      await server.start();
      console.log("making a post request");
      app.use(
        "/graphql",
        cors(),
        json,
        expressMiddleware(server, )
      );
    })();
  } else {
    app.use(`/${name}`, services[name]);
  }
}```
````

I did try changing from **localhost** to **127.0.0.1**  also to my IP adress after running ipConfig on my cmd on windows but still gettin** POST /graphql** not found when doing a request to  http://localhost:4000/graphql endpoint both on postman and the browser. The server is running correctly with this message logged on my console ** Server ready at http://localhost:4000/graphql**

from the browser i get this

```
Not Found
404
NotFoundError: Not Found
    at C:\Users\user\whatsapp business api\crm-whatsapp\server1\index.js:74:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\user\whatsapp business api\crm-whatsapp\server1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\user\whatsapp business api\crm-whatsapp\server1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:328:13)
    at C:\Users\user\whatsapp business api\crm-whatsapp\server1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:9
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\user\whatsapp business api\crm-whatsapp\server1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\user\whatsapp business api\crm-whatsapp\server1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at cookieParser (C:\Users\user\whatsapp business api\crm-whatsapp\server1\node_modules\cookie-parser\index.js:71:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\user\whatsapp business api\crm-whatsapp\server1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\user\whatsapp business api\crm-whatsapp\server1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:328:13)
    at C:\Users\user\whatsapp business api\crm-whatsapp\server1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:9
```